# Spring Oauth2 not working for me - Status Not Answered

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying out Oauth2 with Spring security. I am trying to call the /getresource service in my resource class by following the below

1. GET http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &client_id=my-first-client
    &redirect_url=http://localhost:8080/getcode
    &scope=read
2. Get the code and call the Authorization service to get the auth token by doing 
   POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
   grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXXX
3. Get the token and call the /getresource rest service. 
   by 
   GET http://localhost:8080/getresource
   Header : Authorization: Bearer <>

But I have been getting the below error

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Any help will to locate the issue will be greatly appreciated.

My Authorization class

```
package auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthProvider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer{
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthProvider.class, args);
    }
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     String uname_query = "select username,userpass,enabled from users where username=?";
        String role_query = "Select username, role_name from user_roles where username=?";

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(uname_query)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(role_query);
    }

/* @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/","/login","/home","/403","/oauth/**","/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/getresource").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");


    }*/

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-first-client")
        .secret("password")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token","password")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
        .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/authcode")
        .resourceIds("testresource");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

My Resource class

```
package auth;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class Resource {

    private static final String resourceid="testresource";

    @RequestMapping("/getresource")
    public String getResource()
    {
        return "Hello Everyone!!";
    }

    private static class Resourceconfigurator extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(Resource.resourceid);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/","/login","/home","/403","/oauth/**","/resources/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/getresource").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: have you set scope read?? because you are checking for `hasScope('read')`..and its better to check for roles instead of scopes..

Comment: @PrasannaKumar I tried this http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-first-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/getcode&scope=read but failed. You mean hasRole instead of scope? I will try that but my issue is I am not even getting the login page to authenticate. if I try login that is also giving me full authentication required message.

Comment: Is request coming to controller?? and also uncomment the `configure` method in security config..

Comment: @PrasannaKumar I tried that but no luck. I un commented the configure method inside the AuthProvider class and commented the one in resource and vice versa. and I also had both un commented but still the same. The request is not coming to the controller as it is blocked by the security filter.

Comment: Change to '.antMatchers("/getresource").permitAll()' this and let me know whether it will work or not